# Datatable is having excessive top padding

Tags: c#, jquery, css, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I made a web application, with a database linked in it. I used the database to display the users that have registered in the webpage (not published, thus its all made up data). I used datatables.net for the design of my table, following this videos: https://youtu.be/s3o8iuoDMyI?list=LL
https://youtu.be/U0zYxZ6OzDM?list=LL

But I am not exactly getting the desired result in my display of my table:

database table now:

[image: Table having excessive top padding]

I tried removing any `padding` elements in my code for the page, but it did not change anything. What have I done wrong?

Code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Admin Page";
    string[] TableHeaders = new string[]
    {
      "First name"
      ,"Last name"
      ,"Email"
      ,"Phone Number"
    };
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
    body {
        display: flex;
        background: #222831;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
        color: snow;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        font-family: Kalam, cursive;
    }
    .table{
        background:#fff;
        overflow-y:auto;
        box-shadow:0px 10px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border-radius:10px;
        padding: 5rem;
    }
    table{
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table thead th,
    table tbody td{
        padding:15px;
        border:none;
        font-weight:600;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    table thead th{
        background: #1861ac;
        color:snow;
        font-size:16px;
        position:sticky;
        top:-1%;
    }
    table tbody td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    nav{
        display:none !important;
    }
</style>

<div class="table">
    <table id="Users" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @{
                    foreach (var head in TableHeaders)
                    {
                        <th>
                            @head
                        </th>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var Acc in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Acc.Fname</td>
                            <td>@Acc.Lname</td>
                            <td>@Acc.Email</td>
                            <td>@Acc.PhoneNO</td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you ask on the [Datatables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/)? People there are generally pretty responsive.

Comment: ouh I'll ask there too. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Try the using the browser's inspector to see what styling may be applied to that area.

Comment: Think I found what is causing the distance, but its like, I did not write it in my script tag. so it says: `table.datatable{ border-collapse: seperate !important; }` Can I rewrite it in my style so that i can change it smh?

Comment: @UnfreeHeX  Did it work when adding `!important` to your DOM element?

Comment: not sure, but it sort of worked when i changed the `border-collapse: seperate !important` to `border-collapse: collapse !important`

Comment: @UnfreeHeX I think this case is ended, you can post your style setting as the answer : )

Comment: Alright @TinyWang

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments above, The attribute that removed my excessive height between my content part and the headers, is the `border-collapse`. It was initially `border-collapse: seperate !important`, in which changed that to `border-collapse: collapse !important`; It was not about any paddings (that's what I initially thought). Anyways, Here's my whole `style` block for further reference:

```
<style>
    body {
        display: flex;
        background: midnightblue;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 940px;
        color: snow;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        font-family: Kalam, cursive;
    }
    .table{
        background:#fff;
        overflow-y:auto;
        box-shadow:0px 10px 50px 0px snow;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 2rem;
    }
    table{
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table thead th,
    table tbody td{
        padding:15px;
        border:none;
        font-weight:600;
        font-size:14px;
    }
        table thead th {
            background: #00113a;
            color: snow;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: sticky;
            top: -1%;
        }
        table.dataTable {
            clear: both;
            margin-top: 6px !important;
            margin-bottom: 6px !important;
            max-width: none !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
    table tbody td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    nav{
        display:none !important;
    }
</style>
```